# How to correctly include classes in c++?

Tags: c++

I would like some clarification about including classes in c++. I don't know the good way to do it because i don't know the differences between theme

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h" // Is it enough to include like this? ? 

class B; // what this line does ? 
class A : public B // what public B does here ?
{
    // .......
};
```

So how do i know if i should use **class b** or **public B** or juste a **#include "B.h"** ?
I hope i was clear enough and thanks for the help

Comment: class B;   line forward declares it ---  just saying there there is some class B.

Comment: Code you have would make a linker error, if class B was not actually ever declared.

Comment: Look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: In short.  Forward declaration lets you use a class, before it's been defined.  -- Without forward declaration, you would have to put full implementation of class B before class A

Comment: ... but you can't use forward declared classes as base classes.

Comment: After including B.h I'd expect the forward declaration of `B` to be unnecessary. If it is necessary, you probably have a bug or B.h is very poorly named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> #include "B.h" // Is it enough to include like this? ?
> ```

Yes.

> ```
> class B; // what this line does ?
> ```

This is an alternative to including B's header. Doing both is redundant.

It gives you less freedom. It allows you to create pointers and references to `B`, but not create instances of it, nor inherit from it, nor access its members.

On the other hand, `class B;` compiles faster, and can be used to break circular include dependencies.

> ```
> class A : public B // what public B does here ?
> ```

Class A inherits from class B, publicly. Read about inheritance in your favorite C++ book.

Comment: Covers the specific question better than the proposed dupe/related.